# "Sort by random" in OSX Finder setting kMDItemFinderComment to a random hash for every file in a folder?

Tags: python, bash, macos, finder, ableton-live

Finder allows you to sort files by many different attributes.

In the OSX filesystem, there is an attribute on every file called "comments" (`com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment`) which allows you to add any arbitrary string data as metadata for that file.

Finder exposes this "comment" attribute in the GUI and you can "sort" by it. I thought I could abuse this attribute to fill in random data for the each files "comments", and then sort by those random comments.

**tldr**; I'm trying to create "sort by random" functionality (in Finder) with the help of a BASH script and some python.

this does work to achieve that (sort of):

```
find $1 -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; #get a list of files in the dir
  do
  if [[ $file == *.wav ]]
    then
        hash=$(openssl rand -hex 12); #generate a random hash
        osxmetadata --set findercomment "$hash" $file; #set the comment
    fi
done
```

here i'm using the [osxmetadata](https://pypi.org/project/osxmetadata/) python utility to do the heavy lifting.

and while it works as intended, but it's **really** slow:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7exk.gif

i'm trying to do this operation on folders with many items, and would frequently be "re-seeding" the files with random comments.

can anyone suggest an optimization i can try to make this faster? i tried using `xattrs` but that doesn't seem reindex the comments in finder when they update.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap the then-clause in a `(...)&` and add a wait after the loop. Then it will do every file in parallel.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. `&` worked on a test case (about 50 files) much more quickly, but it choked on a directory of 3000 files.

Comment: @AK Have you tried to profile the script to see where it spends most time? Does the file explorer being open or closed have any effect?

Comment: i'm not totally sure how to do that; i do not notice any performance change with Finder open or closed. @TobiasFendin